# if data have 2 field then it must be shown twice in angular.js table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular.js table. I'm receiving data. this data is in data :D

```
var dataArr = [
0: "aaa",
1: "bbb"
]
```

and I have checker, if data.length > 0 and then must be shown twice.
for example:
`var user1 = {name: "george", field: [0: "aaa"]}` <<< this user must be shown in table once.

`var user2 = {name: "Fred", field: [0: "aaa", 1: "bbb"]}` <<< this user must be shown in table twice and so on...

I'm using ng-repeat to write data in table:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
<div>{{item.name}}</div>
<div>{{item.field}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you'r trying to achieve? It's somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: `[key:"val"]` isn't a valid expression - did you mean `["aaa","bbb"]` or `{0:"aaa",1:"bbb"}`?

Comment: @Emissary this is an array and into the array we have numeric fields:

Comment: var arr = [
0: "asfaf",
1: "fasfafa"
]
maybe I wrote this array incorectly but you will understand what i mean

Comment: @JakaKonda I already wrote example into the answer.

Comment: $scope.data = response.data;

Comment: Based on the data above, if I understand correctly what you what is something like this:

george | aaa
Fred     | aaa 
Fred     | bbb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your answer, you'd like to get something like this:

```
George aaa
Fred bbb
Fred ccc
```

From data:

```
people = [
    { 
      "name": "George",
      "field": ["aaa"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Fred",
      "field": ["bbb", "ccc"]
    }
  ];
```

To get this, you can use nested angular repeats like:

```
    <div ng-repeat="person in people">
      <div ng-repeat="field in person.field">
        {{ person.name }}
        {{ field }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
I think your data should like this.

```
$socpe.dataArr = [{0: "aaa",1: "bbb"},{0: "aaa",1: "bbb"}];
$socpe.data = [{ 
  "name": "George"
},{ 
  "name": "George2"
}]
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
   <div>{{item.name}}</div>
   <div>{{dataArr[$index][0]}} {{dataArr[$index][1]}}</div>
</div>
```